# Как сделать одноразовую кнопку в телеграм боте?

Tags: python, telebot, aiogram

Мне нужно чтобы кнопка keyboard была одноразовой и реагировала на повторный запрос текстом по типу.."Попытка исчерпана".
Подскажите, как можно это реализовать ?
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Ну если нужна просто одноразовая клавиатура, которая пропадает после нажатия то просто

```
markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard = True)
markup.add(...)
```

Ну а если вы не хотите чтобы она пропадала, то придется слегка помучаться, так как по факту вам нужно где-то хранить факт нажатия на кнопку. Это либо FSM, либо БД, либо ну просто текстовый файлик. Последний вариант для айограма не очень так что покажу на примере FSM.

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext

from data import config

bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


@dp.message_handler(text="Кнопка 1")
async def button_1(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        if data.get("button_1") is True:
            await message.answer("Кнопка 1 нажата")
            return
        # Первое нажатие кнопки
        data["button_1"] = True
    

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    markup.add("Кнопка 1")
    await message.answer("Start", reply_markup=markup)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```